# Running vulkaninfo returns error: vulkaninfo.h:477: failed with ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED

Tags: 64-bit, vulkan, ubuntu-20.04, wine, mesa

Iḿ trying to get vulkan to work but I get the following error:

```
vulkaninfo
ERROR: [Loader Message] Code 0 : /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_radeon.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
ERROR: [Loader Message] Code 0 : /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_intel.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
/build/vulkan-tools-KEbD_A/vulkan-tools-1.2.131.1+dfsg1/vulkaninfo/vulkaninfo.h:477: failed with ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED
```

Following command dumps:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0046] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Dell Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [1028:0410]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

I have added the following to my grub config and initialized it

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash amdgpu.si_support=1 radeon.si_support=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1 radeon.cik_support=0"
```

followed by a reboot. The result is the same error :(

what am I doing wrong, can anyone help me?

Before I forget I installed vukan and mesa vulkan drivers and am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a Dell Latitude E4310. Please help, I just want to play some windows (directX11) games with Wine.

Comment: Just to make things clear, the 2 errors regarding 32-bit libraries are expected on a 64-bit system with 32-bit libraries installed, since vulkaninfo will try to load all available (see `/usr/share/vulkan/icd.d`) libvulkan libraries, both 64-bit and 32-bit. These errors are unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of cryptic error message can happen because `vulkaninfo` doesn't find any supported GPU.

It is likely that your GPU is not supported by Vulkan (too old), and so you won't be able to use DXVK (DirectX to Vulkan). You still may be able to run games without Vulkan by forcing Wine to use WineD3D (DirectX to OpenGl) instead. See **Xaero_Vincent**'s [answer](https://old.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/gaku6y/gaming_on_linux_without_vulkan/fp0e755/) in [this](https://old.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/gaku6y/gaming_on_linux_without_vulkan/) reddit thread:

> In Lutris you can easily disable DXVK as a option and on steam you can
> force OpenGL-based WineD3D:
>
> PROTON_USE_WINED3D=1 %command%
>
> You'll notice though that DirectX 10/11 games will generally run
> slower under OpenGL and some games will likely have graphics
> artifacts, since DXVK is more mature and further developed.